# Closedness of a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Let C be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $r$ be a positive real number. Show that the set
>
> $D = \{y ∈ \mathbb{R}^n:\exists x ∈ C : ||x − y||=r\}$
>
> is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $ ||x|| = (x_1^2 +· · ·+x_n^2 )^{1/2}$ for $x = (x_1 , . . . , x_n ) ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$

I think the given set is similar to a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with center at some point $x$. Any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S(c,r)= \{x: ||x-c||=r\}.$  Then $D= \cup_{c\in C}S(c,r).$

Suppose $(x_m)$ is a sequence in $D$ that converges to $x.$ For each $m$ there is $c_m\in C$ such that $x_m\in S(c_m,r).$ Note that $||c_m||\le ||c_m-x_m||+||x_m||=r+||x_m||$. Because $(x_m)$ converges, $(x_m)$ is bounded. Therefore $(c_m)$ is bounded. Thus some subsequence $c_{m_k}$ converges to some $c\in \mathbb R^n.$ Because $C$ is closed, $c\in C.$ We then have

$$||x-c||=\lim_{k\to \infty} ||x_{m_k} -c_{m_k}||=\lim r = r.$$

Thus $x\in S(c,r) \subset D$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $D$, that converges to some $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $$r-||x_n-x||=||x_n||-||x_n-x||\leq||x||\leq||x-x_n||+||x_n||=||x-x_n||+r$$
As $||x-x_n||\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, so $$||x||=r$$

Comment: how do you say $r-||x_n-x||=||x_n||-||x_n-x||$?

Comment: @vidyarthi $r_n \in D$, so $||r_n|| = r$

Comment: You're showing the closed sphere is closed. The question is a different one.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma where is $r_n$ defined? and how do we get $||r_n||=r$? do we use triangle inequality?